# Web2py vs django for beginner web programmer

Tags: python, django, web2py

I am very interested in learning web programming.. I want to use something from python but not sure if I want to use web2py or django.. Django seems difficult to set up for a beginner such as myself.. But I do not want to throw it out just yet.. Soo what are some expert opinions on web programming frameworks? Also, if django really isn't as hard as it seems, could someone please explain how I would set it up. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a beginner also. I started in about 8 months ago knowing no computer science, programming, powershell, or even html/css, and now I just about have a full django website ready, minus some minor issues because I need video and video is still above my head and hard to find info/learn about.  Anyway, if you don't already know html/css, I used codecademy.com to learn that and some javascript, then learnpythonthehardway.org to learn python, followed by djangobook.com for django.  All are great resources. They even point you in the direction of other things you need along the way. It won't be easy, but there are great learning resources available, and since I myself began learning, codecademy has also added python. I quit my job to focus on programming full time so that I can learn it while chasing a dream, so I know from personal experience that it can be done with the free resources available online. I still don't know A LOT and it will take time for things to start clicking, but if you want to learn it just start.  I know you asked for expert opinions, and trust me I'm no expert, but from my experience django wasn't too bad.  Yeah, you will find yourself banging your head against the wall from time to time, but communities like stackoverflow can also help you figure out answers to your questions. I don't however have any experience with web2py so I can't speak about that.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and I don't know what your experience level is, but google is your friend.  If you get stuck, google it. For instance, if you get an error, copy/paste it into google and you are likely to come up with a good explanation, at least early on.  Once you get into more specialized areas the resources might begin to get a little slim, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let me suggest you give a try for both frameworks, test Django, then test web2py. take which you like more. All good frameworks.

For web2py I suggest: http://killer-web-development.com/